# How to set overwrite to true with IBMQ?

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

I'm trying to get setup with https://qiskit.org, but I'm having a problem.

I have dug around the internet for a bit and haven't been able to find anything.

When I try to run `IBMQ.save_account('api_token')` it says that I already have credentials present, and to set overwrite to true in order to overwrite the current ones.

How do I do with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in the method documentation, `overwrite: Overwrite existing credentials.`:

```
IBMQ.save_account('api_token', overwrite=True)
```